# Formula From Opportunity to Opportunity Team Member

Tags: formula

Is it possible to create formula from Opportunity to OpportunityTeamMember ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a formula field on the Opportunity object that pulls data from team member records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't, as OpportunityTeamMember has a lookup relation with Opportunity and not a parent/child (also known as master/detail).

Comment: Thank You for the information